# Shift images LEFT or RIGHT - Beamer

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

How can I shift the whole image with the caption?

**\hspace*{4cm}** moves only the image without the caption.

```
    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Complementary to Absolute Temperature (CTAT)}

    \begin{figure}[] 
    \begin{circuitikz}[american,node distance = 30pt] \hspace*{4cm}
    \draw (0,0) node[ground]{} to[Tpnp,name=Q1] node[right,yshift = -0.6cm]{$Q_1$} ++(0,1) to[short] ++(0,1) node(v1){} to[I,invert,l^=$I_0$] ++(0,2)node[tground]{};
    \draw (Q1.B) |- (0,0);
    \draw (v1) to [short] ++(1,0) node[below,xshift = 0.2cm]{$v_D$} to [open,o-];
    \end{circuitikz}
    \caption{CTAT}  
    \label{fig:CTAT}  
    \end{figure} 

    \end{frame}
```

[image]

Comment: Please make your example compilable. Otherwise, a `\centering` would probaby help.